# JavaScript/HTML: Changing an image border onclick

Tags: javascript, html

I want to write a function that surrounds an image with a border frame each time i click on it. unf. i can't make it work. deny any typos cause i didn't copy paste it. the function works. but no affect is being made on the image when clicking on it. did i access the border attribute right?

my function:

```
<script>

function mark(imageId) {
    document.getElementById(imageId).style.border = "1";
}

</script>
```

my html body:

```
<input id="imageId" src="\images\image1.png" onclick="mark(imageId)"/>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your markup doesn't *quite* make sense, but:

```
<input id="imageId" type="image" src="http://goo.gl/UohAz" onclick="mark(this)"/>

function mark(el) {
    el.style.border = "1px solid blue";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8QGkq/

Comment: Great works! and what is the right attribute for cancelling this border to the default no border style?

Comment: @JaredFarrish , After select and unselect there is still a blue shadow there , can you please tell how to remove it ? and yes +1 for the answer :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't want `getParameter()`.  You want `getElementById()`.

You also don't want the variable name `imageId` surrounded by quotes inside the function declaration for `mark()` because that changes it to a string.

And as @John Girata points out, you want to specify more than just "1" for the border value.

```
document.getElementById(imageId).style.border = "1px solid black";
```

Furthermore, you need to quote "imageId" in your onclick attribute:

```
<input id="imageId" src="\images\image1.png" onclick="mark('imageId')"/>
```

Comment: sorry my bad i did use elementById - still doesn't work.. fixed also the quotes:) still doesn't work

Comment: You also don't want `imageId` in quotes as a parameter for `getElementById()`.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the border to "1" didn't work for me.  Try this:

```
<script>

function mark(imageId) {
    document.getElementById(imageId).style.border = "1px solid black";
}

</script>
```

You'll also need to surround imageId in the HTML in quotes (not sure if that was a typo or not):

```
<input id="imageId" src="\images\image1.png" onclick="mark('imageId')"/>
```

Comment: that's good! now it's working! w3schools said style.border="1" should be enough - i guess not. and if i want to cancel the border should i change it to empty quotes " " ?

Comment: @UdiLivne - See my comment above. I forgot to notify you with the `@username`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a code for that question.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function sayHello() {
        var boyElement = document.getElementById("boy");
        boyElement.style.border = "3px solid red";
    }
</script>
<img src="C:\Users\Acer\Desktop\new web site\js\images\boy.png" id="boy" 
onclick="sayHello()">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

To clarify, setting borders with a DOM element, you need to provide width, color, style like:

```
document.getElementById("ex1").style.border="1px solid #0000FF";
```

w3Schools **actually** says: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_border.asp

Comment: @Jared Farrish - I wasn't really, just pointing out that they __actually__ did give the right answer!

Comment: We're all lucky part of the time. Try [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_dynamic_styling_information), on SO you won't get harassed.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this :

`<img id="CN" src="CN.png" onclick="fnChangeBorder('CN')">`

and define your function:

`function fnChangeBorder(imageId)`

`{document.getElementById(imageId).style.border = "solid #AA00FF";}`